# MySQL Structure - Unique Groups of Users

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I am using MySQL and I need to create a unique group label for different combinations of users. A group just needs at least one user, but the user combinations and the group labels must be unique.

So for example, I have three users and their IDs:

- Larry (1)
- Curly (2)
- Moe (3)

We can start off with three groups that contains a single user each. The names can be whatever a system user sets, so let's just use their first initial. We'll have groups `L`, `C`, and `M`. But now I have a group with Larry and Curly, so I want another group called `LC`. Larry and Curly cannot form another group with a different name, but they can get Moe to make another group `LCM`.

So now, if I have IDs `1` and `2`, I want to be able to make a query that will pull the group `LC`.

I'm currently at a loss on how to do this. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can LM coexist with LC?

Will you have no more than 64 "users"?  If so, then you could implement "groups" as a `SET` datatype or `BIGINT UNSIGNED`.

```
the_group SET ('Larry', 'Curly', 'Moe')
```

Under the covers, that is the same as

```
the_group TINYINT UNSIGNED
```

with the bottom bit referring to `Larry`, the next bit being `Curly`, etc.

```
UNIQUE(the_group)
```

will say that only one row in the current table can refer to a given group.

You have not said what operations you desire to perform on groups, so I won't explain the various ways you can manipulate `SETs` or ints. with these semantics.

**More**

Or maybe you need these tables:

- Groups: group_id, user_id  (many-to-many mapping table)
- Orders: order info..., group_id
- Users:  user_id, username, ...

With a suitable 3-table `JOIN`, you can list all the 'users' responsible for one 'order'.  [Recommendation on many-to-many](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Comment: That's pretty interesting. Basically, orders are put into our system. And based on what group is responsible for the order, I would want to be able to query for the group name. There can be an LM group, along with an LC group. But it's just going to be one group per order. If an order is placed where Larry and Moe are responsible, I would want to be able to find out that they collectively form LM.